# How do i get the center x and y of an image

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How do i find the center x and y of an image.

Comment: Is "2" too magic a number for you?

Comment: @Flydog57: yeah, because it is the number of divisors of a prime.

Comment: it would be nice to ask a question on stackoverflow and have it answered with maturity

Comment: I'm sorry if you felt insulted.  In the version of the question I answered, you said "I do not want to use any magic numbers".  The obvious solution involves dividing by 2 - but 2 is a "magic number", isn't it?  You eventually commented *"worked it out myself - get the string width then divide the image width / 2 and take away the string width /2"*.  That's awfully darn close to what I had said 12 hours earlier (about measuring the string).  I hope you felt my contributions were useful - I meant them that way.

Comment: I wasn’t talking about you. 2 isn’t a magic number if it’s half

Comment: Yes your contributions were very useful

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment - not enough reputation, so I'll get it as an answer. Shouldn't you just use width/2 and height/2?

Comment: actually no. you see i want to center text perfectly. The text could by any size

Comment: Start with @elbowz's center. Then measure the text you want to display (`Graphics.MeasureString`). Then offset down and to the left by half the height and width of the text measurements

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: aspose does not have a measure string method

Comment: @adminadmin: no idea about `Aspose`, but `Graphics` does. What do you mean by "mvc application". You're not going to get a `Graphics` like that in an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: You just add a package

Comment: worked it out myself - get the string width then divide the image width / 2 and take away the string width /2

Comment: its a c# package, mvc can be in c# therefore yes you can.

Comment: @adminadmin: Yes, it's written in C#, but MVC application generally run on servers.  When you are running on a server, you generally don't have access to a `Graphics` object (which your now disappeared code included).

Answer (score 0):

The string width then divide the image width / 2 and take away the string width /2. This allows me to center the text regardless of the width of the string or the height or width of the image